# USB drive shows 'RAW': can't format and can't delete volume

Tags: hard-drive, usb, usb-flash-drive

I have an 8GB USB drive that shows up as 7.46GB RAW in Disk Management (it also says "Healty (Primary Partition)". I don't believe there is any physical damage to the device.

When I right click the the volume, the only options I get are "Change Drive Letter and Paths" and "Format".
The problem is, If I attempt to do any of those, I get an error stating `"The system cannot find the file specified"`.

Using TestDisk, I can get to the "Write" confirmation, but I get `"Partition: Write error"`

Is there any way I can fix this (utilities, programs, TestDisk, etc)? Data recovery is not the goal here (I just want the drive to work again).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Use [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/); install it on a Live USB (basically creating a bootable USB) and boot from it. It'll put you in a simple Linux desktop where you can open the application and fix the drive.

Mine showed up as "unallocated" so I just created a fresh partition there. Drive is now fine and fully working!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had a similar situation and did a couple of things. Cannot confirm which one was 'the one', but it worked. I'm using Win8, btw.

- Opened diskmgmt.msc
- Clicked on the 'raw' disk / partition (it was the same)
- Changed the drive letter to L
- Applied the change
- Opened the Control Panel
- 'Hardware and Sound'
- Device Manager
- Double clicked the driver, under disks
- On 'policies', changed to Better Performance and then back to Quick Removal
- Disconnected and connected back the disk (using the safe removal)
- Back to the Disk Management, mark the disk to go offline
- Tried to format it using the format only recognized by Win8 (I can't recall now the name)
- It failed, but when I tried to mark back the format to MBR, it worked fine

Hope this helps.